# Adding spark-csv package in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, apache-spark, pycharm, pyspark, spark-csv

I have successfully loaded spark-csv library in python standalone mode through

```
$ --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

[Running the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwciJ.png)

While running the above command, it creates two folders(jars and cache) at this location

```
C:\Users\Mahima\.ivy2
```

Inside it there are two folders. One of them contains these jar files- org.apache.commons_commons-csv-1.1.jar, com.univocity_univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar, com.databricks_spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar

I want to load this library in PyCharm(Windows 10), which is already setup to run Spark programs. So I added .ivy2 folder to the **Project Interpreter Path**. 
Mainly the Error I'm getting is:

```
An error occurred while calling o22.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
```

Full error log is as follows:

```
16/06/27 12:54:02 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Mahima/PycharmProjects/wordCount/wordCount.py", line 10, in <module>
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('flight.csv')
File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 137, in load
return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 45, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "C:\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
... 14 more


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I already added the jars to the project interpreter path. Where am I going wrong? Please suggest some solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add an environment variable named as "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS" and set its value to "--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 pyspark-shell". It will work fine.

Comment: I've read so many SO topics about this and none pointed to such a simple solution of the problem. You're life saver, buddy!

Answer (score 1):

- sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv') on your console does not garantee that the package is actually installed until you execute a proper command on it. In fact the command

  ```
  sqlContext.read.format('com.dummy.csv')
  ```

will not return any error either

- you can add package to your spark context

  ```
  sc.addPyFile("com.databricks_spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar")
  ```
- you can open a csv file in one line with no package needed

  ```
  sc.textFile("file.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(",")).toDF
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes on the console the following command is running:    sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv'). I tried adding the jar files using sc.addPyFile as you pointed, but I'm still facing the same error(An error occurred while calling o25.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv.)